# Not able to import log4j classes in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am getting started with log4j and i am stuck at the very first point which is to import the classes successfully and to make it run.

I have already added the external jars for log4j 1.2 api -2.14.1
But i am unable to import the classes.

[This is my code with all the jars i have imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezJRB.png)

[This is the exception i am getting after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDxiL.png)

Edit:
So i did a bit of digging myself and sorted the above error by the below steps:

1. Go to your project properties by right clicking on it .
2. Go to "Java Build Path".
3. Go to Libraries and Select JRE
4. Edit and Set Exxeecution Environment to JRE 1.1

Answer (score 1):

I see you have log4j-api but you also need log4j-core installed as well.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the solution but i actually did not made any changes in my code other than the ones mentioned in my post(Edit) section and it worked well for me